# In PHP is it better to code first even if it is messy and then apply coding style?

Tags: coding-style

Once the code works, we have all the time in the world to make it look good.

If we need to make sudden rapid changes, then we have no choice other than messing up standard coding style.

Is this way professional and widely used? Or is it better to form the habit of maintaining perfect order while coding at every point in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like wasted time and inefficiency to me, revisiting the same code twice.
Just my opinion, of course!

Once you decide on your coding style, it becomes natural, and doesn't take any longer to code neatly than it would to code scruffily...

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. Should try to stick with one of the coding style.

Answer (score 5):

What usually happens is that, once the code works, something *else* urgent pops up. Then something else. Repeat until you can no longer remember how the original code works sufficiently well to be able to clean it up. *If* you ever get time to do that.

When you say "I'll fix it up later", you have to realise that "later" will probably never come...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really consider just typing out messy code - I tend to stick to the formatting standards the rest of the team are using.

Making use of an editor that enforces formatting helps, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to make it work if it's easy to read and you can see what's going on.

"Sudden rapid changes" create bugs in my experience!

Changes would be quicker and easier to make if the code was legible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are coding: a simple script or a full application and complex interlinking scripts/classes.

In the first case you can write code that works and then apply some simple reformat/refactoring based on your taste or not.

In the second case it is always better to follow strict formatting standards, code will be readable across the whole team and you won't have to do the same work twice.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the general opinion - bugs appear as a result of quick fixes urgently required. Therefore you need to write a quick fix. After few of these your code becomes hardly maintainable. Also, after the project is ready for some short period (that doesn't require quick fixes for a week or two), the client rarely pays for additional changes and refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a lively topic of debate, how to code. Whilst I agree that going overboard at anytime is a waste of time and energy, likely to show limited ROI, undertaking any and all coding with a professional attitude is a must.

As @john-yeates said so rightly, when you take the attitude of, "I'll come back to it later", later *never comes* as there will always be something else that is "*more important*" or "*more urgent and pressing*".

At the very least, even if your organisation doesn't have a formalised standard, what it does have, should be followed *consistently*, every time, by every developer in your organisation/company/not-for-profit; no matter how junior, intermediate, or senior they are.

There's no excuse for sloppy coding and it only hurts everyone later. At least, even if the quality of the code is poor or average, if it's consistently written, the time taken by new maintainers of it, or an existing maintainer returning to it after months away, it will take less time to understand and come up to speed on.